# How to express a decimal time in HH:MM

Tags: r, time, format

I have a time in decimal format: `22,13` in hours and I would like to express this in R as `HH:MM`. I mean, `22:08` (depreciating seconds)

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scan the string into `s` as numeric, divide it by 24 so that we can convert it to `times` class (as `times` expects a fraction of a day), round it to minutes and remove the trailing `:00`

```
library(chron)

x <- c("22,13", "5,20") # test data

s <- scan(text = x, dec = ",", quiet = TRUE)
sub(":00$", "", round(times(s/24), "min"))  ##
## [1] "22:08" "05:12"
```

If you prefer to truncate the seconds rather than to round to the nearest minute then replace `round` with `trunc` in the line marked ## or replace that entire line with:

```
format(as.chron(s/24), format = "%H:%M")  # truncate
```

### Converting back

If `y` is the result of the line marked ## then these convert back to `times` class and to number of hours respectively.  We have used `round(..., 2)` in the last line to get the same number of digits as the original input but if that is not important it could be omitted.

```
y <- c("22:08", "05:12")

tt <- times(paste0(y, ":00"))
tt
## [1] 22:08:00 05:12:00

round(24 * as.numeric(tt), 2)
## [1] 22.13  5.20
```

Answer (score 4):

The syntax `%02.0f` is to round the value to an integer and make it always be 2 units. Therefore, `7.8` minutes will be converted to character `"08"`.

```
x <- c("22,13", "9,25", "7,8")

sprintf("%02d:%02.0f",
        as.numeric(sub(",\\d+", "", x)),
        as.numeric(sub("\\d+,", "0.", x)) * 60)

# [1] "22:08" "09:15" "07:48"
```